# Adding dummy data to a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to add/display dummy data in a column when there are no rows in the output.

Ex: I have written a query which sometimes returns data. But if there is no data, I wan to display one of the column as "No Data Available".

Here is the initial query I am using:

```
select CaseNumber,[Description]
from table1
```

I tried using:

```
SELECT CaseNumber,
       CASE
         WHEN CaseNumber IS NOT NULL THEN [Description]
         ELSE 'No Data Available'
       END AS [Description]
FROM   table1
```

It is not working. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: By "no data", do you mean if the field "CaseNumber" is NULL ?

Comment: Works for me. How is it 'not working' - are you getting an error?

Comment: Yeah, if there is no data at all

Comment: Don't do it, you'll regret it later. This should be done in your UI layer.

Comment: Do you mean you want to show "no data available" when there are no records returned ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a default row for a query that returns no rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285666/how-to-set-a-default-row-for-a-query-that-returns-no-rows)

Comment: Hi @Steve.  Take a peek at these questions ([here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)).  They should help you to rephrase your question.  If we can better understand you I'm sure the answer will follow.

Answer (score 0):

You need `IF/ELSE` block not `CASE` statement

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   table1)
  SELECT CaseNumber,
         [Description]
  FROM   table1
ELSE
  SELECT Null as CaseNumber, 'No Data Available' as [Description]
```

Considering you want to display some dummy data when the `select` query does not return any records

**Demo :**

**schema**

```
CREATE TABLE table1
  (
     CaseNumber    INT,
     [Description] VARCHAR(40)
  )
```

Running the query with no records present

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   table1)
  SELECT CaseNumber,
         [Description]
  FROM   table1
ELSE
  SELECT NULL                AS CaseNumber,
         'No Data Available' AS [Description]
```

**Result :**

```
CaseNumber  Description
----------  -----------
NULL        No Data Available
```

Inserting some records into your tab;e

```
INSERT INTO table1
VALUES      (1,
             'test date')
```

Now running the query with records present in the table

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   table1)
  SELECT CaseNumber,
         [Description]
  FROM   table1
ELSE
  SELECT NULL                AS CaseNumber,
         'No Data Available' AS [Description]
```

**Result :**

```
CaseNumber  Description
----------  -----------
1           test date
```

Comment: @Steve You need to explain *empty output*. If possible sample data and expected result. Your question leads to so many guesses

Comment: Ex: select CaseNumber,[Description]
from table1 where Name = 'Steve'                                                     returns output as                                                                                                                                               CaseNumber: 1234 Description: Hello Steve                                                                                                                         Now if there is not data with Name "Steve", I am trying to display : CaseNumber: NULL  Description: "No Data Available"

Comment: I am afraid its still not showing any output. Just curious, did you try/test this query if there is no data in the table?

Comment: @Steve - Added demo.. check and tell if it is still not working for you :\

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried `ISNULL` function?

```
SELECT 
    CaseNumber,
    [Description] = ISNULL([Description], 'No data available')
FROM table1
```