# sql select a default row if the result is not found

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

Suppose that I have table that holds some data for individuals and companies, and I want to retrieve default value if no data found for individuals or companies, for example, suppose that I have a table

```
CustomerAccountId   CustomerAccountType     DueDays     IsAdjustable    isDefaultForIndividual  isDefaultForCompany     
1                   Individual              10          true            false                   false
2                   Company                 20          false           false                   false
null                null                    5           false           true                    false
null                null                    30          true            false                   true
```

I want to create a function that takes two parameters `IndividualCustomerAccountId` and `CompanyCustomerAccountId` if `IndividualCustomerAccountId` found in the table retrieve it, if not found retrieve the default value for individuals which is the `third row` in this case `, the same for companies, if the`CompanyCustomerAccountId`is found retrieve it, if not get the default value for the companies which is`fourth row` in this case.

suppose that we created a funtion which accepts `IndividualCustomerAccountId` as the first parameter and `CompanyCustomerAccountId` as the second parameter

## **sample input**

`MyFunc(1 , 2)` should return `first and second rows`

`MyFunc(1 , 50)` should return `first and fourth rows` because no company with `CustomerAccountId` `50` found in the table so retrieve the default value for companies which is the `fourth row`

`MyFunc(100 , 2)` should return `second and third rows` because no individual with customer account Id `100` is found so we get the default value for individuals which is the `third row`, and we have a company with `customerAccountId` 2, so we simply can retrive it from the table.

I want to create either a LINQ query or SQL function to achieve these results

Comment: [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/285823/5707687)

Comment: I'm going to assume normalizing your data is not an option? A better design would be easier to query.

Comment: @Crowcoder you're right but unfortunately we can't change DB design now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try SQL function

```
CREATE TABLE Customer 
(
     CustomerAccountId int,
     CustomerAccountType varchar(20),
     DueDays int,
     IsAdjustable bit,
     isDefaultForIndividual bit,
     isDefaultForCompany bit
)

INSERT INTO Customer VALUES
(1, 'Individual', 10, 1,0,0),
(2, 'Company', 20, 0,0,0),
(null, null, 5, 0,1,0),
(null, null, 30, 1,0,1)

GO 

CREATE FUNCTION MyFunc
(
 @IndividualCustomerAccountId int,
 @CompanyCustomerAccountId  int
)
RETURNs @result TABLE 
(
     CustomerAccountId int,
     CustomerAccountType varchar(20),
     DueDays int,
     IsAdjustable bit,
     isDefaultForIndividual bit,
     isDefaultForCompany bit
)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @result 
    SELECT CustomerAccountId , CustomerAccountType, DueDays, IsAdjustable,  isDefaultForIndividual,isDefaultForCompany 
    FROM Customer c
    WHERE (CustomerAccountId = @IndividualCustomerAccountId AND CustomerAccountType = 'Individual')
            OR (CustomerAccountId = @CompanyCustomerAccountId AND CustomerAccountType = 'Company')

    IF(NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Customer c
                    WHERE CustomerAccountId = @IndividualCustomerAccountId AND CustomerAccountType = 'Individual' ))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @result 
        SELECT CustomerAccountId , CustomerAccountType, DueDays, IsAdjustable,  isDefaultForIndividual,isDefaultForCompany 
        FROM Customer c
        WHERE   CustomerAccountId IS NULL  AND isDefaultForIndividual = 1
    END

    IF(NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Customer c
                    WHERE CustomerAccountId = @CompanyCustomerAccountId AND CustomerAccountType = 'Company' ))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @result 
        SELECT CustomerAccountId , CustomerAccountType, DueDays, IsAdjustable,  isDefaultForIndividual,isDefaultForCompany 
        FROM Customer c
        WHERE   CustomerAccountId IS NULL  AND isDefaultForCompany = 1
    END

    RETURN;
END

GO


SELECT * from dbo.MyFunc(1,2)
SELECT * from dbo.MyFunc(1,50)
SELECT * from dbo.MyFunc(100,2)
SELECT * from dbo.MyFunc(100,50)
--DROP TABLE Customer
```

Demo link: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/IIOS60102)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can run an IF Exists with your query to see if there is going to be any data. If so, go ahead and run your query. If not, do a select default row.

```
If Exists (your query)

       (your query)

Else

        SELECT 'query for default row'
```

I hope its clear your problem.
Happy Coding.Thanks